# I don't know what's wrong with this jQuery function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

This is the jQuery code:

```
function Pages(className, contant){

    $(className).click(function(){
      var x = $(this).attr('rel');
      $.post('ajax/pages.php', {'namePage':x}, function(page){
        $(contant).html(page);
      });
      return false;
    });

  }

Pages('.pageName' , '#contant');
```

and this is the PHP code:

```
if(isset($_POST['namePage'])){

    $page = strip_tags(addslashes($_POST['namePage']));
    $url ='contorls/'.$page . ".php";
    if($page == 'homepage'){
        include_once '../view_pages/homepage.php';
    }else{
        if(is_file($url))
        include_once $url ; 
    else
        header ('Location: view_design/notfound.php');
    }

}
```

this is the HTML code:

```
<li><a class="pageName" href="" rel="homepage"><span>dashbord</span></a></li>

<li><a class="pageName" href="" rel="Emplooy"><span>قسم الموظفين</span></a></li>
```

Why does this function work only with the first link?

Comment: You might want to make the question title a little bit more descriptive

Comment: Your updated code should work for both...still an issue? make a jsfiddle..

Comment: When I see a question saying that something "doesn't work" without explaining *in which way* it doesn't work, I'll vote to close as unclear or lacking sufficient information 9 times out of 9. "It doesn't work" doesn't give anyone a starting point for examining the problem. Explain what results you're getting and how they differ from the intended results, and include any error messages you received.

Answer (score 1):

The second link doesn't match `".pageName"` because it doesn't have the class `pageName`.

Change to:

```
<li><a id="pageName2" class="pageName" href="" rel="Emplooy"><span>قسم الموظفين</span></a></li>
```